# Extract string from a pattern preceded by any length

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to extract a string from a file name

eg if filename format is  "anythingatallanylength_123_TESTNAME.docx", I'm interested in extracting "TESTNAME" ... probably fixed length of 8. (btw, 123 can be any three digit number)

I think I can use regex match  ... 
".*_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].docx$"

However this matches the whole thing. How can I just get  "TESTNAME"?

Thanks

Comment: why not use the `string.Contains() and Substring methods or IndexOf()` to get the `starting position and the length -` regex seems a bit of overkill in my opinion

Comment: @MethodMan Regex is made for matching pattern exactly like that one... not overkill at all IMHO.

Comment: I know @Lucero but different ways to skin the same cat.. `IMHO`

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say TESTNAME can be any string, of fixed length 8.
Also as pointed out somewhere, possibly may vary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Lucero @noob @JamesFaix I came up with ...

@"(?<=.**[0-9]{3}*)[A-Z]{8}(?=.docx$)"

So a look behind (in brackets, starting with ?<=) for anything (ie zero or more any char (denoted by "."  )  followed by an underscore, followed by thee numerics, followed by underscore. Thats the end of the look behind.  Now to match what I need (eight letters). Finally, the look ahead (in brackets, starting with ?=), which is the .docx

Nice work, fellas. Thunderbirds are go.

Answer (score 1):

Use parenthesis to match a specific piece of the whole regex.
You can also use the curly braces to specify counts of matching characters, and \d for [0-9].

In C#:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"*._\d{3}_([A-Za-z]{8})\.docx$");
```

Now "TESTNAME" or whatever your 8 letter piece is will be found in the captures collection of your regex after using it.

Also note, there will be a performance overhead for look-ahead and look-behind, as presented in some other solutions.

Comment: I believe the .* to match any char any number of times was a required element of this regex as stated by vicente.

Comment: Oh, that period, well there just escape it with a backslash.  Sorry.

Comment: One char at a time, that's what I always say!

Comment: Better. Note however that `\d` is not equivalent to `[0-9]` as it will also match other decimals such as arabic ones `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`... careful ;)

Comment: @Lucero, thanks for the heads up.  Sometimes I forget about non-Latin character sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a look-behind and a look-ahead to check parts without matching them:

`(?<=_[0-9]{3}_)[A-Z]{8}(?=\.docx$)`

Note that this is case-sensitive, you may want to use other character classes and/or quantifiers to fit your exact pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to improve my answer. +1 for that.

Comment: @noob Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your file name format **"anythingatallanylength_123_TESTNAME.docx"**, the pattern you are trying to match is a `string` before `.docx` and the underscore `_`. Keeping the thing in mind that any `_` before doesn't get matched I came up with following solution.

**Regex:** `(?<=_)[A-Za-z]*(?=\.docx$)`

**Flags used:**

- `g` global search
- `m` multi-line search.

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=_)` checks if there is an `underscore` before the file name.
- `(?=\.docx$)` checks for extension at the end.
- `[A-Za-z]*` checks the required match.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ4hE7/3)**</kbd>

Comment: You should add an end anchor... ;)

Comment: I don't know what's the context of matching. For example if OP is trying to match only the file name or is he trying to match file names from a huge string.

Comment: The specification seems quite clear to me, with the "anythingatallanylength" at the beginning of the string but nothing like that at the end. And the OP actually also had an anchor in place, which is hardly unintentional.

Comment: Yes it is, but removing the `$` makes it to match if you have large data. And also it matches in this context. Thus useful at large.

Comment: @Lucero: If you have noticed I have also kept the length variable because OP said **probably fixed length of 8**. Thus taken care of that uncertainty too.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "at large". I still think it should be anchored, as this will also match: `anythingatallanylength__.docx\TESTNAME.pdf` but that's not what the OP asks for, is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104913/discussion-between-noob-and-lucero).

Comment: I can see what you are all doing now ... I've decided to use the Look ahead /behind and came up with ...

(?<=.*_[0-9]{3}_)[A-Z]{8}(?=\.docx$)

Is this right? I think it is because I think it works.

Actually, perhaps i will place the starting anchor?

@"(?<=^.*_[0-9]{3}_)[A-Z]{8}(?=\.docx$)";

Is this seems to work ... what are your thoughts?

Comment: @vicente Yes, this would work. However, since you accept "anything" on the left-hand side you don't need the start anchor and the `.*` - it will do the same without. In general (to keep the regex shorter and improve matching performance), it's best only to match the parts really required to match and not more.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks very much to all of you, lucero noob jamesfaix. I's a shame I'm going to answer my own question, because I would not have been able to were it not for all your answers.

Comment: @vicente: am glad it helped you.